# Why does java not allow a generic super typecast, but allows it via a wildcard cast?

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I've got this function:

```
Table<Record> tableOfRecord() {}
```

And a type `TableRecord<R extends TableRecord> extends Record`. And I have this other function:

```
<R extends TableRecord<R>> Table<R> table(Table<R> table, String filtered) {
    // ...
    return (Table<R>) tableOfRecord();
}
```

The above fails to compile:

```
error: incompatible types: Table<Record> cannot be converted to Table<R>
```

However, this compiles and runs fine:

```
return (Table<R>) ((Table<?>) tableOfRecord());
```

I am not sure why this is allowed, but the previous example is not.

Comment: I don't know.  But neither is semantically correct, AFAICS - a `Table<Record>` is not a `Table<R>` unless `R` is `Record`, which is impossible here.

Comment: Look at your compiler warnings. It's shouting "unchecked cast". >hat you're doing is almost equivalent to `return (Integer) ((Object) "hello");` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Most generic information is erased at runtime. The JVM sees a cast of ```Table``` to ```Table```, and can not confirm that this cast is actually type-safe (which it actually is not). Hence the unchecked cast warning you get when casting generics.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal to cast from `Table<Record>` to `Table<R>` because it can be proven at compile time that no object can be both `Table<Record>` and `Table<R>`, and thus the cast is guaranteed to be incorrect. It is illegal to write a cast that can be proven at compile time to be incorrect.

`(Table<R>)(Table<?>)tableOfRecord()` is a sequence of two separate casts, one from type `Table<Record>` to `Table<?>`, and one from `Table<?>` to `Table<R>`, each of which is legal because each cast, by itself, is not known to be incorrect at compile-time.